# Ubuntu 15.10: CIFS not mounting on bootup

Tags: boot, mount, fstab, cifs

I'm trying to mount an IOmega NAS drive through `fstab`, but it doesn't mount on boot. All devices are on the same 192.168.1.x network.

After running `dmesg`, what I get is:

```
[    1.916474] CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
[    1.916844] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -101
```

My `fstab` reads:

```
//192.168.1.29/Musica         /mnt/hmnhd-ticroj/music     cifs    _netdev,gid=xxx,uid=xxx,credentials=/home/xxx/credentials.txt,rw    0   0
```

so that, after booting, the manual mounting:

```
$ sudo mount -a
```

works fine.

Actually, this `fstab` file worked also fine with Ubuntu 14.04, and stopped working when I upgraded to 15.10. I have the feeling that `fstab` doesn't wait for the network, even though the option `_netdev` has been included, but this is just my feeling.

Any ideas?

Comment: I do a similar mount but I don't use the _netdev, gid, or uid options.  My line in fstab looks like this.  the important part might be `nobootwait`.  `//192.168.1.2/Digital\040Photos /media/ST8-Photos cifs credentials=[credential file],iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,nobootwait 0 0`

Comment: I have tried using your options, but, unfortunately, it didn't solve the problem. After a verbose manual mounting, I also get a strange message: Credential formatted incorrectly: (null). All drives are properly mounted, though.

Answer (score 2):

comment=systemd.automount fstab parameter helped me.

Example fstab:

```
//host/share /media/user/share cifs _netdev,comment=systemd.automount,credentials=/path/to/.smbcredentials,sec=ntlm,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777   0 0
```

[Reference](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1023737#c5)

Comment: If you could make that answer more detailed it would be nice. A link to a website may change and  your answer would be lost as the internet is not a static place.

Comment: The option you suggested seems to have done the trick. Good job!